# change tint color of UIBarButtonItem

Tags: swift

I would like to change the text color of my UIBarButtonItem.
Current color is "system blue"

I tried this:

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(exit))
button.tintColor = UIColor(red: 126.0, green: 189.0, blue: 11.0, alpha: 1.00)
```

The rgb values should show a green color - but the button text color shows white.
Where is my fault ?

Comment: `RGB` has a value between `0` and `1`, try `UIColor(red: 126.0/255.0, green: 189.0/255.0, blue: 11.0/255.0, alpha: 1.00)`

Comment: ahhh okay ... it works! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set values between `0` to `1` for `RGB Colors`. Use the following

`UIColor(red: 126.0/255.0, green: 189.0/255.0, blue: 11.0/255.0, alpha: 1.00)`

OR

`UIColor(red: 0.49, green: 0.74, blue: 0.04, alpha: 1.00)`